# Strange markings on SMT resistors

Tags: resistors, surface-mount, network

The other day, a network card was acting up (even thought the software didn't report any functional problems, the network didn't connect in duplex). On checking the board visually, I found these resistors at the network interface:

[image]

Even though `X` probably means x0.1, I've never seen the symbol at the other side of the `5`. I suspect the value to be 50 Ohms (to present the correct impedance to the line).

Any helpful reference?

Comment: There's a hint of ferrite bead about them.

Comment: that looks like an `iSX`

Comment: Nah, not an i, the body of the i is an open square. It's rather an \$ \bar{o}\$

Comment: @Andyaka, I doubt it's a ferrite bead. I doubt magnetics have been miniaturized to that extent. Also, none of the ferrite components I've seen carry markings at all.

Answer (score 1):

After some more detective work, it seems that the strange symbol [image] is actually an `8`. Which means that the resistor has to be read as `85X`, which is [EIA language](https://www.hobby-hour.com/electronics/eia96-smd-resistors.php) for `750`. The `X`, as suspected, is a multiplier by 0.1, so the result is 75 Ohm. This corresponds to a typical cable termination network.

I first thought all the Rs with the symbol were the same, but at the border of the camera's sight I found:

[image]

which is `68X`, or, translated, is 499 times 0.1, or 49.9 Ohms.

Though I've yet to find an authoritative answer, I'm quite sure this is correct. For some reason, the rest of the resistors on the board have the 'normal' 3-digit codes.

Learned something new...

Comment: Interesting, have you made any measurements? in-circuit, out of circuit?

Comment: Yes, different manufacturers use one of the two methods so it’s not uncommon to have mixed boards. I really don’t like their proposed solution of no markings at all.